# Steps involved in sending a post request in Python to login to website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

*I've read tons of questions like this here but still haven't managed to solve my problem*

I'm trying to login to [this](https://www.puregym.com/Login/) website using Python but am not being able to.

I've found the form I wanted to fill

```
<form id="loginForm" class="form" method="post">
    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="email" class="form__label">Email Address</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="false" name="associateAccount"/>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,64}$" class="form__input" placeholder="Enter Email Address" title="The email address must valid to continue." maxlength="63" autocomplete="email" required=""/>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <label for="pin" class="form__label">Pin Number</label>
        <input type="password" name="pin" required="" id="pin" class="form__input" maxlength="" placeholder="Enter Pin" title="The pin must be valid to continue"/>
        <span></span>
        <a class="text-link text-link--forgotten-pin" id="ForgottenPinLink" href="/forgotten-pin/">Forgotten Your Pin?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <input type="submit" id="login-submit" class="button button--primary button--wide button--large" value="Login"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

but am facing the following problems:

- Where can I find the link the form is POSTing to? (there is no action attribute)
- From the form, how can I create the payload?

I've tried various things (with urllib, mechanize, and requests) but was now trying this

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.puregym.com/Login/'
payload = {'email':'myusername', 'pin': 'mypin'}
r = requests.post(url, params=payload)
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

and the problem is always the same, it just returns the same page I was in. I figure this code is incorrect since I'm posting to the wrong url but again, I don't know where to find the correct one.

I'd really like an explanation on how to break down this problem with actual python code if possible.

**EDIT:**

Inspecting the POST request with Chrome Developer Tools, I got

```
Request URL: https://www.puregym.com/api/members/login/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 123.45.57.89:123
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Also, the payload is (replacing my credentials)

```
associateAccount:"false"
email:"myemail@email.com"
pin:"1234567890"
```

However, this code

```
import requests

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {"associateAccount":"false", "email":"myemail@email.com", "pin":"1234567890"}

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.puregym.com/api/members/login/'

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print p.text

    # An authorised request.
    r = s.get('https://www.puregym.com/members/')
    print r.text
```

just returns

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The current code is

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

payload = {
    "associateAccount":"false", 
    "email":"test@gmail.com",
    "pin":"123456789"
}

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en,pt-PT;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,tr;q=0.6",
    "content-type": "application/json, text/javascript",
    "referer": "https://www.puregym.com/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2Fmembers%2F",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5)",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

POST_URL = 'https://www.puregym.com/api/members/login/'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.puregym.com/Login/'

# Scrape the login page first to get __RequestVerificationToken from form
page = urllib2.urlopen(LOGIN_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
form = soup.find("form", {"id": "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm"})
__requestverificationtoken = form.input.attrs['value']

headers['__requestverificationtoken'] = __requestverificationtoken

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(POST_URL, data = payload, headers = headers)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print(p.text)
```

but the response is

```
{"errorCode":"P2BBD16-190139","message":"We have had a little problem which is normally only temporary. You can try again or contact our Member Services Team on 03444 770 005 (between 8am and 10pm) who can help."}
```

but logging in via the browser works just fine.

Comment: If there is no `action` attribute then the form may be posting to the same page as the form is on. However, check that JavaScript is not being used to submit the page first - turn off JS in your browser, and see if the page still lets you log in?

Comment: You could use [selenium webdriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to do this. I'd recommend searching the web for a basic selenium tutorial. Selenium is a tool that basically automates the web browser.

Comment: I've looked into Selenium but actually I think there must be a way of doing this with requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your post should also have headers (not just a payload). Importantly for this one, the `__requestverificationtoken` is likely the site's csrf token which is meant to improve security.

```
payload = {"associateAccount":"false", "email":"myemail@email.com", "pin":"1234567890"}
headers = {
           "__requestverificationtoken": "_Q4aj4hNp5uOMv6EbrD8KRQA85nsLLKRQIAC8m2PHNAvI2OHfUrtW11MANIjJVWWhqFJTjq1wHGMhCLj4AyLYCUcEqA1",
           "accept": "application/json, text/javascript",
           "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
           "content-type": "application/json",
           "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
           }

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.puregym.com/api/members/login/'

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers = headers)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print(p.text)
```

I don't have an account to test your login-required page, but the above code returns `"Your email address or PIN is incorrect. Please try again."` which suggests that the code is functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Reid. I tried this code with my credentials and it still returned `{"message": "An error has occurred."}`. The credentials are correct because when I use them outside the script they work. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Can you try it with incorrect credentials to see if you receive the same response as my code? If you don't get the `address or PIN is incorrect` message, then it may be something else in your code.

If that doesn't work, pull the rest of the Headers from Chrome Developer Tools and see if that works. I had removed the other headers because they didn't seem to influence the output I was getting, and the server does not always require all of them.

Comment: My code is exactly like yours with `import requests` added and my credentials replaced. I logged in online with my credentials copy-pasted from the script and was successful (did this thrice). However, running the script returns the `Your email address or PIN is incorrect. Please try again.` error, just like it did to you. I was now inspecting the headers used but my `_requestverificationtoken` is different from yours. Should this be a static value or does it change with every POST request?

Comment: Yeah, looking at the page you can find another form with id "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" that the webpage pulls this token from. So in order to make this work consistently, you'll want to first load the login page, scrape the token from that form, and then proceed as normal.

Comment: I added that code and it didn't work still, I've updated the question to include the full code as well as the current error. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: You changed the `content-type` header to `application/json, text/javascript` which it doesn't understand. Change it back to just `application/json` and your code gives me the `Your email address or PIN is incorrect` message.

Comment: Also, you already have a `requests.Session` running, so you can just use that to get the `__requestverificationtoken` rather than importing urllib2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173400/discussion-between-mcansado-and-reid-ballard).